# How to make random images load in ImageView? (Android)

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview

I'm a begginer Android Developer
And in my app I want to make a random image
load out of a list of images every time then app is launched.
Genneraly, I want to use ImageView because its simple,
but you have to mention what image to load in the layout file or
main.XML.

I don't know how to do this so please help. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not required to set the image in the .xml file

Say, you have an ImageView in your layout (say its main.xml)

### main.xml

```
<ImageView>
    android:id="@id+/myImageView"
</ImageView>
```

### In your Activity

```
int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03};

// Get the ImageView
setContent(R.layout.main);
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

// Get a random between 0 and images.length-1
int imageId = (int)(Math.random() * images.length);

// Set the image
mImageView.setBackgroundResource(images[imageId]);
```

Hope this helps (:

### Edit

1. The index of the image array should not be hard coded
2. Corrected the syntax error. Thank you Tom for pointing it out :)

Comment: I think that this is the best way to do it... The 3 should ve a variable, setted by the array's size, but it's fine

Comment: Other thing, u should round the value, cause these cast could generate an error, use `Math.round((Math.random() * images.length))`

Comment: I'm the curious type of programmers, so what do you mean by hard coded? And what happens when you define an array by the following: int[] images?

Comment: Hard code means to use the exact value. Like `int month=11;` it's a bad practice, because you will need to change it when December comes. A better practice is to call something like `int month=getMonth();`, which `getMonth()` gets the exact month from the system or somewhere else

Comment: Don't you mean: int[] images = new int [] {R.drawable.image01, R.drawable.image02, R.drawable.image03}; ?